# How do I return a resultset object from a remote method?

Tags: java, jdbc, rmi, resultset, serializable

The idea is to pass a query to a remote method, have that remote method execute it and let it send the result set back to the calling method.

Here is the caller method

```
btnOK.setOnAction((e)-> {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM schoolmanagement.director;";
    System.out.println("Calling RMI");
    try {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost");
        RMIInterface rmi = (RMIInterface)registry.lookup("remoteObject");
        System.out.println(rmi.Query(query));
    } catch (RemoteException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NotBoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

And here is the remote method

```
public String Query(String query) throws RemoteException {
    try {
        Connection mycon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schoolmanagement", "root", "root");
        Statement mystatement = mycon.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = mystatement.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString("Name") + " "+ rs.getString("Age"));
        } 
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I know that `rs` is not serializable. How do I work around this?

Comment: It isn't a `String` either. Not making much sense.

Comment: @EJP return rs is just until I get a solution. I'm not actually trying to return an object while the method is of type String.

Comment: So what are you talking about? Your title says pass `ResultSet` *to* a remote method, your question says return it *from* a remote method, and your code doesn't do either.

Comment: @EJP It was my mistake. Ill change the title to " returning a result set from a remote method".

Answer (score 3):

`ResultSet` is not serializable because it does not actually contain all the results, it is more accurate to think of it as an iterator or a pointer into a list.

So in order to send the results over RMI you will have to actually extract the results and store them in for example a list of records (or list of Director objects in your case).  Make sure those objects are all serializable.